# Does ( P(B|A) - P(B|~A) ) / P(B|A) have a name?

Tags: probability, bayesian, terminology, likelihood-ratio

Without going into the details, which are unnecessary here, this morning I found uses for the quantity

$$ S = \dfrac{P(B|A) - P(B|\overline A)}{P(B|A)} , $$

something like the amount of "probabilistic specialness due to a condition". Like likelihood ratio, it's a comparison of ***P(B|A)*** and ***P(B|not A)***, but perhaps in some ways even more natural.

For instance, if today has a 30% chance of rain given that it's spring, and would have a 20% chance of rain otherwise (given not spring), then the difference is 10%, which we then divide by 30%, giving 33%. So 33% of spring's rain chances are correlated with it being spring instead of another season.

If, instead, we imagine the spring chances were 1%, and non-spring were 0%, then ***S*** would be (.01 - 0) / .01, or 100%. In this way, values are normalized to 100%.

My current feeling is that this might be a natural way to associate conditions with events. If ***S*** is high, then we would be prone to saying, "It's raining, ***S(rain|spring)*** is close to 100%, therefore rain is characteristic of spring, and it's probably spring". Something like logical abduction.

I'd like to know if this has a name in probability theory (and just generally how it might appear).

Comment: there is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_risk_reduction

Comment: I think that's it exactly. Please write a solution (copying text from Wiki instead of linking), and I'll mark it as the answer. Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At least in epidemiology, the term is
[Relative Risk reduction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_risk_reduction):

> the relative risk reduction (RRR) or efficacy is the
> relative decrease in the risk of an adverse event in the exposed group
> compared to an unexposed group. It is computed as ${\displaystyle
> (I_{u}-I_{e})/I_{u}}$, where $I_e$ is the incidence in the exposed
> group, and $I_{u}$ is the incidence in the unexposed group.
> If the risk of an adverse event is increased by the exposure rather than decreased, term relative risk increase (RRI) is used, and computed as ${\displaystyle (I_{e}-I_{u})/I_{u}}$.
> If the direction of risk change is not assumed, a term relative effect is used and computed as ${\displaystyle (I_{e}-I_{u})/I_{u}}$

[Dictionary of Epidemiology - Oxford Reference](http://www.oxfordreference.com/view/10.1093/acref/9780199976720.001.0001/acref-9780199976720)

Comment: (And the more general term "relative effect")

Comment: This term is also called the "avoidable risk" is epidemiology.